# How to show web page to specific DIV (height wise)

Tags: html, css

I have Got 10 DIVs in my page each DIV contains content like images,text, slider, video etc.

lets suppose these DIVS are in this order.

class="DIV 1"

class="DIV 2"

class="DIV 3"

class="DIV 4"

so on up to 10 DIV.

**I want to show my page to DIV 5 on every screen like laptop monitor etc.**

i.e. whenever page loads on any screen (whatever the height is) it should show up to DIV 5.

I tried applying this css to DIV 5 but it didn't work.

```
    .DIV5
 {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
 }
```

it goes down in heights like 768px.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `height: 20vh;` for your divs, in this case, 5 first divs should take 20% viewport each, and 6th div will be out of screen at loading.

Edit : Updated JSFiddle

Please see the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zymbhkcy/1/)

Comment: should i give height 20vh to only first div or all from 1-5?

Comment: I would give 20vh to each div (1 - 10) in order to keep a beautiful feeling in your design, but it depends on your needs.

Comment: when i give 20vh to every div  from top i mean div 1 div 2, div 5 starts going further downward. That doesn't fix my issue

Comment: It is due to default body's CSS rules, I updated my Fiddle with no margin/padding on body and it works